# MassTransit scheduler consumer does not update prometheus metrics

Tags: masstransit

I have a project with MassTransit (7.2.2) + RabbitMQ + Hangfire with enabled MassTransit prometheus metrics via MassTransit.Prometheus. I've noticed that messages sent or published by scheduler consumer do not update metrics. It results in no **mt_publish_total** and **mt_send_total** metrics for scheduled messages. Metric **mt_delivery_duration_seconds** also show infinite delivery time for such messages. Can anybody expected similar issue?
It looks like a bug, but maybe any additional configuration is required.

All run within single service.
Scheduler is added by **AddMessageScheduler** method.
Hangfire is added by **UseHangfireScheduler** method.
Metrics are enabled by **UsePrometheusMetrics** method and exposed by promethous-net via endpoint within the same application.
Lack of the specified metrics we can be observed on the /metrics endpoint.

Registration code looks like this:

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(config =>
{
    config.AddMessageScheduler(new Uri("queue:my-scheduler")
    config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UsePrometheusMetrics(serviceName: "my.service.name");
        cfg.UseHangfireScheduler("my-scheduler");
    });
});
```

Comment: Additional details, such as where the scheduler is running (your code, standalone, etc.), has prometheus been added to that service, are that services's metrics being scraped as well?

Comment: I've completed the question.

Comment: What about where you're running Hangfire itself?

Comment: Hangfire is also running within the same application. It's the reason I wonder why messages send/published from Hangfire don't update metrics. It's clear that Hangfire hosted in another service would require separate configuration/registration of metrics mechanism. All scheduler's messages like ScheduleMessage or CancelScheduledMessage update metrics correctly. The problem only affects the scheduled messages themselves.